# need to make a ticker that will also listen for incoming commands, but what style of multithreading to use?

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

I think I'm just going to use my already existing statusStrip.  Text is all I need to work with so that'll make things easier.  I want my ticker to rotate through a List<> or something, displaying each item for specified duration.  I also want to be able to, at any time, call my ticker and get it to immediately display a string that I pass to it.

So, my question is which style of threading/thread pattern..etc?  I've been reading here: http://www.albahari.com/threading   and have been totally absorbed with this guy's work.  I don't understand it all yet but I would like some suggestions to point me in the right direction...I've tried using Timer and it doesn't seem like the right approach...BackgroundWorker?  I dunno, the thing doesn't really have to do much work..just  display items on a loop....Any  advice please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an observable class:

```
Ticker : IObservable<Ticker>
{
    // fulfill IObservable's contract
}
```

Then, a TickerReporter:

```
TickerReporter : IObserver<Ticker>
{
    // fulfill IObserver's contract
}
```

Where you would notify `TickerReporter`, use any number of asynchronous techniques to display the message. This is the `IObserver<T>/IObservable<T>` pattern.